# isLoading property not available in the Auth0ContextInterface class

Tags: react-native, expo, auth0

Why is the `isLoading` property missing from `useAuth0`?

I have a react-native project using Auth0 for authentication that was originally created using Expo CLI, but have had to eject Expo due to pipeline and native dependency concerns.
Now when attempting to access the `isLoading` property that is supposed to be available through `useAuth0()` I get an error saying:

> Property 'isLoading' does not exist on type 'Auth0ContextInterface'

I'm stumped at this point, and I haven't been able to find anyone else who's had this issue.

I have looked over node_modules/react-native-auth0/src/hooks/auth0-context.js and .../auth0-provider.js and can see the `isLoading` property initialized there. But when I look at the `Auth0ContextInterface` class, which is located in a declaration file in node_modules/@types/react-native-auth0/index.d.ts., `isLoading` is not declared there.

I attempted to add it to the interface, but it always returns false even though it should be initialized to true. So it doesn't appear to have any connection to the `auth0-context.js` or the `auth0-provider.js` files.